# Linux Clock Architecture

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, clock

In Linux how is the Clock Architecture implemented. 
There is a file `include/linux/clkdev.h`

```
struct clk_lookup {
    struct list_head    node;
    const char      *dev_id;
    const char      *con_id;
    struct clk      *clk;
};
```

What are the various fields and it is extensively used in Clock architecture in `arch/arm/Board***/...` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generic Linux clock infra-structure is documented in [clk.rst](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/driver-api/clk.rst).  For the ARM, Sasha Hauer created the *common clock* frame-work recently (last two years).  The clocks are structured in a *parent/child* relation.  Typical SOC (system on chip) has main clocks created from a crystal which are either scaled down (with a counter) or up with a PLL and maybe both.  They hierarchy is important for power savings.  Usually devices are only using one of the *lowest/youngest* clocks in the tree.  When a device requests a clock, the infra-structure ensures that all parents are started.

Previously (legacy), clocks were passed from the *machine file* (reference `arch/arm/Board***/`) to the driver/device via platform data; ultimately through `platform_device_register()`.  Sometimes, the clocks were/are derived from the device name.  For example the *fec* driver might use *fec-clk*.  This did not work well for **multiple machine** configurations, so the [platform data](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/driver-api/driver-model/platform.rst) mechanism was introduced.  Even newer machinery uses a **dt** (or device table).  Here, there are no machine files, only a device table that is passed from the boot loader to the kernel.  In this case, the **dt** tells the driver which clock to use.

Originally, the `dev_id` and `con_id` were to relate clocks for a **device** and clocks that are **connected** (parent/child).  Usually either `dev_id` or `con_id` are NULL as only one aspect is needed.  I think that this view was found wanting; especially for starting an entire **clock chain**.  So, depending on the Linux version, the answer varies.  Even in the current source, some platforms (like `orion`) still use an older mechanism.  I don't think `orion` supports **[device trees](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree)**.

Specific answers will depend on your Linux version and the machine (and possibly platform) in use.
See also: [clkdev.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/clk/clkdev.c), [clk.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/clk/clk.c)

**Open source - There are many mutations. They all have a different plan.**<sup>[BSG re-imaged](https://io9.gizmodo.com/battlestar-galacticas-ronald-d-moore-admits-the-cylons-1796020590)</sup>

Reference: [Russell Kings message on ARM clkdev](http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-dev/2011-October/007952.html), original did not imply ordering.

Comment: See: [LWN's ARM kernel consolidation](http://lwn.net/Articles/443510/), which has a good overview of some recent changes; how *clocks*, *device trees* and *drivers* work together.

Comment: when the devices have PLLS and counters which can be enabled then why do we need clock framework?

Comment: The devices use the clock framework to manipulate the PLLs (and counters).  You don't code the PLL manipulation in a driver; the clock framework does that and handlers inter-dependencies in the clock tree.