# [Common Clock Framework]: How to set rate of a muxed clock if its parent clock unable to set?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, clock

Studying [`Common Clock Framework`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/clk.txt) and have a doubt related to `muxed` clocks.

If we want to set particular rate of a `muxed` clock and the current parent of the clock is unable to set the desirable rate (parent have lesser rate).

Then, Is there any function or mechanism who switches the parent of the clock (from its parent list) automatically and sets the desire rate?

One possible solution, we can call the `set_parent()` manually and then call `set_rate()`, which can set desire rate. But what if we just call `set_rate()` and it swithces parent of the clock automatically and sets desirable rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clocks may *up-scale* a timer using a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop).  So having a parent that has a lower clocking doesn't mean that automatically trying to increase the parent clock is the best solution.  The *[Common clock framework](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/clk.txt)* (*CCF*) is meant to allow multiple drivers/sub-systems access to a shared resource.  The *CCF* doesn't try to be intelligent as the way different clock trees behave is difficult to know generically.

> One possible solution, we can call the `set_parent()` manually and then call `set_rate()`, which can set desire rate.

I think you mean to call `get_parent()` and then use `set_rate`?  Some of the time, it is not easy to call `set_parent()` as it maybe fixed.  You need to read your SOC documentation.  In some cases, there are multiple input clocks available.  Ie, the real clock hierarchy is not a tree but a DAG although the **active** hierarchy is tree-like.

> But what if we just call `set_rate()` and it switches parent of the clock automatically and sets desirable rate.

This might make sense for your SOC clock that you are looking at but not generically.  There maybe dozens of clocks dependant on a parent and it maybe possible to re-rate *grand-parents*, etc.  It is probably not the best choice to re-rate the system clock because an audio driver wants a clock that is a few HZ out?

It is possible to write the *clock driver* so that it will re-rate the parent if a request is made on a child that doesn't work.  However, this is part of the clock drivers and not the *CCF* generally.

---

### Example

For instance, an SOC might have an audio clock with three input sources,

1. A dedicated 48000khz
2. Some low speed bus clock (platform general)
3. A USB clock

Option 1 is the best sound quality with the highest power consumption.  Option 2 is meant to be generic but may not match sound rates well resulting in sub-optimal DAC/wave/sound generation.  Option three might be good for some sort of USB sound slave, but if you are not using USB this may be expensive for power consumption.

In the case above, `set_parent()` maybe a way to get the desired rate, if the SOC clock driver supports it.

---

There is no intelligence in the *CCF*; if there is some flexibility it is in the *clock driver* but this depends on the clock hardware.  It is up to a programmer to read the SOC documentation and determine what is the best way to configure the clock tree.  Probably you should also examine the clock driver for your SOC and Linux version to see what it is supporting.  You can not generically change the clock rate of parents in a driver as other devices may depend on them.  If you need this for a particular SOC in an SOC family, you need to special case it by examining a device tree to see which SOC the driver is running on.  This is the case where you can use `get_parent()` and `set_rate()` for the particular SOC.

Reference: [A question on older Linux clock structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239352/linux-clock-architecture).

Comment: In the latest version of kernel (v=3.18), found api `__clk_mux_determine_rate()` which helps to finding best parent to provide a given frequency. This can be used directly as a determine_rate callback (e.g. for a mux), or from a more complex clock that may combine a mux with other operations.