# PLL register configuration generates an interrupt (ARM)

Tags: c, assembly, arm, interrupt-handling

I am working with an ARM device produced by Infineon. There seems to be a problem which I can't seem to find a solution to when **configuring PLL**. When configuring the register holding N, P and K value for a normal PLL mode, the code produces an interrupt and doesn't pause afterwards. Here is the code as shown in the Disassembler (Eclipse):

```
1333          SCU_PLL->PLLCON1 = (uint32_t)((SCU_PLL->PLLCON1 & ~(SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_NDIV_Msk | SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_K2DIV_Msk |
08000cc8:   ldr r1, [pc, #252]      ; (0x8000dc8 <XMC_SCU_CLOCK_StartSystemPll+400>)
08000cca:   ldr r3, [pc, #252]      ; (0x8000dc8 <XMC_SCU_CLOCK_StartSystemPll+400>)
08000ccc:   ldr r2, [r3, #8]
08000cce:   ldr r3, [pc, #252]      ; (0x8000dcc <XMC_SCU_CLOCK_StartSystemPll+404>)
08000cd0:   ands r3, r2
1334                                         SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_PDIV_Msk)) | ((ndiv - 1UL) << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_NDIV_Pos) |
08000cd2:   ldr r2, [r7, #4]
08000cd4:   subs r2, #1
08000cd6:   lsls r2, r2, #8
08000cd8:   orrs r2, r3
1335                                         ((kdiv_temp - 1UL) << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_K2DIV_Pos) |
08000cda:   ldr r3, [r7, #16]
08000cdc:   subs r3, #1
08000cde:   lsls r3, r3, #16
1334                                         SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_PDIV_Msk)) | ((ndiv - 1UL) << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_NDIV_Pos) |
08000ce0:   orrs r2, r3
1336                                         ((pdiv - 1UL)<< SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_PDIV_Pos));
```

It seems like the code "breaks" on the following instruction:

```
08000cce:   ldr r3, [pc, #252]      ; (0x8000dcc <XMC_SCU_CLOCK_StartSystemPll+404>)
```

In other words, if I use the 'step into' function, it jumps to the following interrupt right before moving onto the 'ldr' instruction shown above. The following are the configurations of N, P and K values that I have used.

```
.syspll_config.n_div = 80U,
.syspll_config.p_div = 2U,
.syspll_config.k_div = 4U,
```

I've been told that the name of the handler doesn't mean much, but here is what Disassembler settles on after the program fails to execute line 08000cce.

```
08000298:   b.n 0x8000298 <VADC0_G3_3_IRQHandler>
```

Also, here is what is shown in the console.

```
Starting target CPU...
Debugger requested to halt target...
...Target halted (PC = 0x08000298)
/.../
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFE8
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFE8
```

EDIT: Perhaps for the sake of completeness I would include a code snippet from system.c file that initializes PLL module with its default values, which **works fine**. It is very similar to the code shown in the first code pane of this question, perhaps with the exception of resetting the affected register values before writing new P, N and K values. I have divided the initialization code into two parts - resetting and setting the values; it appears that the code "breaks" during the reset phase.

```
SCU_PLL->PLLCON1 = ((PLL_NDIV << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_NDIV_Pos) |
(PLL_K2DIV_24MHZ << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_K2DIV_Pos) |
(PLL_PDIV << SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_PDIV_Pos));
```

Comment: It appears that `SCU_PLL` isn't defined correctly.

Comment: @Ross Ridge The base address of SCU_PLL?

Comment: Is your code running from SDRAM?  You are reconfiguring a system clock?  Probably the SDRAM controller/SDRAM BUS goes nuts when you do this.  You have to change the PLL from code in system SRAM;  No 'D' for dynamic and the 'S' is static, not synchronous.  Sit in a loop until the clock locks.  You also need to disable interrupt, etc so that nothing outside SRAM gets called while the PLL settles.

Comment: @artlessnoise I am not very far from a beginner in these sorts of things, but I am willing to learn - could you please suggest a starting point to solving this problem with the approach that you suggested as I have almost no understanding of how to check whether SDRAM is used, etc.

Comment: @Agrus Its likely the `08000ccc: ldr r2, [r3, #8]` instruction that's causing the crash. This instruction performs the read from memory made by the expression `SCU_PLL->PLLCON1`. The other LDR instructions just load from constants embedded with the code, and if those reads were causing the crash then so would the instruction fetches.

Comment: @RossRidge I would not be able to check that until Monday unfortunately, but from the top of my head, a similar code sequence is called in the system.c file that is executed before the rest of the code to initialize all the default values, which does not cause any error. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: How should I know? I can only go by what you've shown.

Comment: @RossRidge That's not quite what I meant - I was looking for a suggestion as to why a similar command in two different cases produces different results while referencing similar addresses and having a similar structure. This problem is really hard to solve without having the device on hand - I understand that and I really appreciate your advice. Hopefully playing around with it further will shed some light onto the source of the problem :)

Comment: What is the exact chip?  The 'technical data sheet' will provide a memory map.  What is at address 0x08000000?  Is it SDRAM or internal RAM?  Also the technical reference will say what the PLL is used for.  See: [Linux clock architechure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239352/linux-clock-architecture) for some idea of how complex the main PLL might be to change.  Ie, there can be dozens of devices dependant on this clock.

Comment: @artlessnoise Memory region starting at 0x08000000 is dedicated to Program Memory Unit Program Flash Bank (cached) - since the read operation to the address within that space returns an error, does this mean that the module/information stored in Flash are somehow corrupted?

Comment: The flash controller might need the clock you are changing.  You have to know the structure of the clocks.  For instance, the Freescale 'nfc'  (NAND flash controller)  needs a clock to operate.  If it is NOR flash, then it is quite possible that it doesn't need a clock and this is not your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being caused by a trap request (promoted to NMI) that was generated upon disconnecting the VCO (voltage-controlled oscillator) from the external oscillator OSC. Disconnecting the two hardware components is important in configuring the PLL registers, however, if the trap request upon loss-of-lock is not ***cleared and disabled***, the following command will generate an interrupt:

```
/* disconnect Oscillator from PLL */
SCU_PLL->PLLCON0 |= (uint32_t)SCU_PLL_PLLCON0_FINDIS_Msk;
```

The command precedes the following line, which is what I thought was originally causing the problem, thus posting it in the question:

```
SCU_PLL->PLLCON1 = (uint32_t)((SCU_PLL->PLLCON1 & ~(SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_NDIV_Msk | SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_K2DIV_Msk | SCU_PLL_PLLCON1_PDIV_Msk))
```

Note that trap request can help troubleshoot problems with the PLL module, therefore they need to be enabled again. However, a trap request is still generated regardless of whether the uC will act on it or not (as decided by enable/disable bit). So, in order to restore trap functionality again, one needs to, again, clear and then enable the module as follows:

```
SCU_TRAP->TRAPCLR |= SCU_TRAP_TRAPCLR_SVCOLCKT_Msk;
SCU_TRAP->TRAPDIS &= ~SCU_TRAP_TRAPDIS_SVCOLCKT_Msk;
```

Along the way I have discovered this interesting article that may help anyone working on ARM uCs and facing unexpected interrupts: [Debugging and Diagnosing Hard Fault & Other Exceptions.](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html)